# Excel VBA form in multiple workbooks

Tags: vba, forms

I have a form that makes list of values from selection as can be seen here:

[image]

I have added the opportunity to enter the list in Excel. I will select the cell and click on "Enter data in Excel":

[image]

But what I would like to do is to have the possibility to enter data to another workbook, but when I select another workbook the form is no longer active.

I know I can reference another workbook and other worksheets in VBA code, but I would like to have the possibility to select the cell in another workbook by clicking on it.

Answer (score 0):

Change the form's ShowModal property to 'False'.  This is found in the object property window when the object is selected in the Visual Basic editor.  That should allow it to remain open when you change workbooks.
[image: sample object properties]